# Simple Landscape Mode not working

Tags: windows-phone-7, landscape-portrait

I have added an XAML Page and tries to make run in landscape mode with the emulator and it is showing me in the potrait mode.

Here is my XAML Page Code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="PhoneApp1.Page1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="70"/>

            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="190"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="290"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Text" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="30,0,0,0"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtAdd" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18.667" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>

        </Grid>
    </Grid>

    <!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
    <!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
                <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
            </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Can anyone say me the mistake I am doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct. Have you "rotated" the emulator? Third button from the top in the small toolbar next to the emulator window itself.

Comment: Yes I have did it :) Iam thinking that there might be mistake with the  emulator as the same thing I have done it with Blend it works pretty well!

Comment: try restarting the emulator :)

Answer (score 2):

Did you ever figure this out? If it's not a problem with your XAML as @Jesper suggested, then it might just be the emulator. I have been using the emulator to test a local website. I was having the same problem with the rotate buttons rotating the phone but the display was still in portrait mode.  I realized that if I had pressed Page Up to use my keyboard then it would always keep IE in portrait mode.  When I pressed Page Down again to use the phone input, landscape worked correctly. Not sure if that is a bug or intentional, but it might be the same thing with other apps.

Comment: Perfect! This also fixes problem with IE showing horizontal portrait when the emulator is in landscape view in the 7.5 emulator as well.